# IAM policy to restrict EBS volume creation above threshold

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-ebs

How can I restrict users to create EBS volume with a size greater than 20 GB? Is there any available policy condition keys to in a policy?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49104681/how-to-limit-ec2-ebs-volume-size-for-ec2runinstances-in-iam-policy help to address (or provide hint) to your query?

Comment: @KishanParekh yeah that helped!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the [Numeric Condition Operators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_Numeric) against the `ec2:VolumeSize` condition. The following would restrict creation of an EBS volume to one of 20GB or less:

```
{
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
        {
            "Sid": "EC2CreateVolume",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:CreateVolume",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "NumericLessThanEquals": {
                    "ec2:VolumeSize": "20"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I actually used "Deny" Effect and "NumericGreaterThanEqual" in the operator. Thanks for the help! :)